# Issue with CDKTF Deployment of Azure Infrastructure in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm, terraform-cdk

I'm encountering an issue while trying to deploy Azure infrastructure using CDKTF (azurerm provider) within an Azure DevOps pipeline.  Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```html
//code setup...

class MyStack extends TerraformStack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, env: Environment) {
    super(scope, id);

    // Azure provider setup and backend configuration...

    const resGroup = new ResourceGroup(this, env.CreateId(resourceGroupId), {
      // Resource group configuration...
    });

    const mainStorageAccount = new StorageAccount(this, env.CreateId(storageAccountId), {
      // Storage account configuration...
    });

    const cdnProfile = new CdnProfile(this, env.CreateId(profileNameId), {
      // CDN profile configuration...
    });

    const cdnEndpointConfig = {
      // CDN endpoint configuration...
    };

    new CdnEndpoint(this, cdnEndpointConfig.name, cdnEndpointConfig);
  }
}

// App setup and environment variables...

const app = new App();

const tfEnvironmentType = process.env.TF_ENVIRONMENT || 'test';
const market = process.env.MARKET || 'A';
let env: Environment | undefined;

if (tfEnvironmentType && market) {
  env = new Environment(tfEnvironmentType, market);
} else {
  console.error('One or more environment variables are missing.');
  process.exit(1); // Exit the process with a non-zero status code to indicate an error
}

if (env) {
  const environmentID = env.GetID();
  new MyStack(app, 'src', env);
  app.synth();
}
```

Azure DevOps pipeline task for deploying with Market A:

```html
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Running Deployment with Market XX
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION)
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    failOnStandardError: true
    inlineScript: |
      cd infrastructure
      export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
      export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
      export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId
      export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
      export MARKET=A # Set Market variable to 'A'
      echo "Deploying infrastructure with Market: $MARKET"
      npm run deploy
```

Azure DevOps pipeline task for deploying with Market B:

```html
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Running Deployment with Market DK
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION)
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    failOnStandardError: true
    inlineScript: |
      cd infrastructure
      export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
      export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
      export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId
      export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
      export MARKET=B # Set Market variable to 'B'
      echo "Deploying infrastructure with Market: $MARKET"
      npm run deploy
```

package.json

```html
    "scripts": {
      "deploy": "cdktf deploy $npm_config_TF_ENVIRONMENT --auto-approve",
      // Other scripts...
    }
```

**I've noticed that deploying the infrastructure for Market B is causing the resources created for Market A to be destroyed. How can I deploy resources for both Market A and B without interfering with each other?** Any help in successfully deploying Azure infrastructure using CDKTF within an Azure DevOps pipeline for different markets would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Thanks @Martin, Besides using separate tfstate files, I found a fix by using different output parameters in my deployment:

Here's how I set it up:

```html
"deploy:A": "MARKET=A cdktf deploy $npm_config_TF_ENVIRONMENT --auto-approve --output=cdktf.out.A",
"deploy:B": "MARKET=B cdktf deploy $npm_config_TF_ENVIRONMENT --auto-approve --output=cdktf.out.B"
```

So, with these commands:

deploy:A for the "A" market.
deploy:B for the "B" market.
This trick allowed me to customize the deployment process as needed. Just sharing this in case it helps someone else out!
Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have experience with AWS cdktf but I think you are missing defining separated state files like for each stack. like:

```
new aws.provider.AwsProvider(this, 'AWS', {
  region: env.region,
  defaultTags: [{ tags }],
});

new cdktf.S3Backend(this, {
  bucket: `martti-data-management-${env.name}-tf-state-${env.region}`,
  key: `accounts/${env.name}/bootstrap/${name}-terraform.tfstate`,
  region: env.region,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the name of the stack according to the environment?

```
 new MyStack(app, 'src', env);
```

vs

```
  new MyStack(app, 'src-a', env);
```

and

```
new MyStack(app, 'src-b', env);
```

The out folder should now build 2 stacks. Just concat the name dynamically, based on your input of which market you build to.

Did this is AWS CDK that way. Not sure if it transfers to cdktf